# Sharing using Intent is not working in Android 5.1 Version

Tags: android-intent, xamarin.android, android-sharing

I am using intent filter to share the PDF files to other apps.It is not working in Android v5.1. But in other version it is working fine. Device having required app. Below is my code. How can we resolve this issue?

```
var pathFile = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal); 
            var m_documentMobiNames = shortName + "." + fileType;
            var mobileFileName = Path.Combine(pathFile, m_documentMobiNames);
            var shareIntentsLists = new List<Intent>();
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.SetAction(Intent.ActionSend);
            sendIntent.SetType("application/pdf");
            var resInfos = context.PackageManager.QueryIntentActivities(sendIntent, 0);
            if (resInfos.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var resInfo in resInfos)
                {
                    string packageName = resInfo.ActivityInfo.PackageName;
                    if (packageName.Contains("com.google.android.apps.docs") || packageName.Contains("com.dropbox.android") || packageName.Contains("com.amazon.kindle"))
                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.SetComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, resInfo.ActivityInfo.Name));
                        intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionSend);
                        intent.SetType("application/pdf");
                        intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, Android.Net.Uri.Parse("file://" + mobileFileName));
                        intent.SetPackage(packageName);
                        shareIntentsLists.Add(intent);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (shareIntentsLists.Count > 0)
            {
                chooserIntent = Intent.CreateChooser(new Intent(), "Share with");
                chooserIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, Android.Net.Uri.Parse(mobileFileName));
                chooserIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraInitialIntents, shareIntentsLists.ToArray());
                chooserIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
                chooserIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                context.StartActivity(chooserIntent);
                await Task.FromResult(true);
            }
```

When i click share it shows **" No apps can perform this action"**

Comment: Have you test it on a real device?

Comment: Yes. Tested in real device

Comment: After looking over your code, you only seem to look for 3 different package names. Does your android 5.1 device have google docs, kindle, or dropbox?

Comment: Yes. Device have google doc Kindle and Dropbox